# Android Studio 3.6.3 build fails for every project without any errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been working with android studio for quiet a time now but i have faced this problem for the first time. **I cannot even see any errors in the Log**, it just says Build Failed. I tried different things as well like downgrading my gradle version and invalidating caches etc. I'm in the middle of an important project would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

[image: Literally a new project]

Comment: did you try deleting .idea folder from project directory?

Comment: @Android_id yes i did a couple of times but nothing. I even reinstalled android studio just now but still the same issue